# openssh: Have ssh add keys to agent as needed

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

When I ssh into a server and my key isn't loaded in the agent, I have to abort, then run ssh-add to get my key into the agent. I'd like the ssh command to add the key automatically if it isn't present, though. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have one key for all your target hosts, or do you have different keys with different passwords? Are you using putty from Windows or are you using an X based windowing system on Linux or are you in a Mac?

Comment: I'm using just one key and openssh. ssh already figures out the right key and asks me for the passphrase, but after I enter it, the key won't get saved to the agent. This behaviour is the same on all POSIX systems and cygwin.

Comment: Does it look similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu

Comment: No, that's different. I want to enter the key password every time the agent is stopped. I'd just like ssh to add the key to the agent directly as needed, rather than having to use ssh-add first.

Comment: Also check out `UseKeyChain` to keep keys between reboots https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `AddKeysToAgent` option does what I want. I can specify `-o AddKeysToAgent=yes` on the command line or add `AddKeysToAgent yes` on a line by itself in my `.ssh/config`. Either works.

It looks like this is a very recent addition to openssh, appearing in release 7.2, dated 2016-02-28!

http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2

Thanks, OpenBSD! I'll be using this a *lot*.

Comment: .ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: AddKeysToAgent. Any thoughts? Unix server

Comment: Check your openssh version. $ ssh -V   . It needs to be newer than or equal to 7.2.

Comment: Indeed that was the case, thanks. Still asks for password after relog though. How to automize git pull via script for example if you always need to enter pass? And i guess password-less id_rsa is not a good idea...

Comment: Do you mean between ssh logins or between local logins? The password is supposed to be erased between local logins.

Comment: Whenever I run a script locally, it should ssh there and run git pull etc., but of course it cant because it needs password for GIT commands (ssh works without because pass is in Keychain, but commands there of course ask for pass)

Comment: Maybe do an agent forwarding? I still don't really understand what it is you're doing.

Comment: Docs: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#AddKeysToAgent