# ssh-add is missing the argument -A to load all keys at once

Tags: ssh-agent

For the past years after a reboot I used to run `ssh-add -A` that loaded all my keys ( the previously i've added with -k ) back to the agent.

But now I received a new laptop ( MacOSX Monterey ) and the `-A` is missing.
I cannot find any other argument that can load back all my keys.

How can I load them all at once then ?

Comment: You mean this ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322124/ssh-add-add-all-private-keys-in-ssh-directory

Comment: @BlockchainOffice no, I used to just run `ssh-add -A` is there a flag that replaces it ? i can't find such, but the answer that you sent, i already saw it, but all these command lines - i can create a script on my own, i just didn't want to , in all servers i just run `-A` simple, this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Maybe this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269121/openssh-have-ssh-add-keys-to-agent-as-needed  looks like -A don't exists for ssh-add

Comment: sorry, i just noticed that `ssh-add` was installed by a 3rd party ( so i had one in `/opt` and another under `/usr/bin` one supported the `-A` and the other didn't.